# Confusion Matrixs for Binary classifier

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I am new to modeling, and I am practicing building a logistic regression model. I would like to create a confusion matrix, but my code doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code for the model (which works):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

#train, test = train_test_split(hp[age], test_size=0.3)

#from sklearn import preprocessing
X = hp['age'].values.reshape((32561,1))
#X = hp[['age','hours-per-week']].values
y = hp['evalinvest'].values

LogReg = LogisticRegression()
LogReg.fit(X,y)
print(LogReg.score(X,y))

0.916710174749
```

Here is where I am having diffculty:

```
# Confusion Matrix
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import *
CM = confusion_matrix(X,y)
print ("\n\nConfusion matrix:\n", CM)
```

---

It runs and outputs results, but I don't feel like it is correct.

Confusion matrix:

```
 [[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [385  10   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [  1   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  3   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [ 33  10   0 ...,   0   0   0]]
```

Then, when I run the following code, it doesn't work:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = CM.ravel()
print ("\nTP, TN, FP, FN:", tp, ",", tn, ",", fp, ",", fn)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-dca3ebbdc69a> in <module>()
----> 1 tn, fp, fn, tp = CM.ravel()
      2 print ("\nTP, TN, FP, FN:", tp, ",", tn, ",", fp, ",", fn)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused on many levels here.

- Logistic regression is a classifier. It gives you the probability that given an $x_{i}$, the probability it belongs to a class or classes.
- So you will be having your `evalinvest` as classes, not continuous values.
- When you call `predict` method on top of trained `LogisticRegression` model, it predicts class for each $x_{i}$ in your test set. So you expect a single array of class labels they belong to.
- `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` function takes in the original class values to the ones that are predicted by the model you had trained and returns what $x_{i}$ has been classified into what class. So it returns an `n(c) x n(c)` array where `n(c)` is the number of classes. So the diagonal of the matrix indicates the number of elements of class `i` being classified as class `i`. And an ideal model should be expected to get this numbers good. The mistake which you had made you sent in your `X` (train) matrix into it and `y` (labels) into it, which is wrong. You are supposed to send in `y_true`(true labels) and `y_pred` (predicted labels from the model). Check the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for more.
- Ideally the function should have thrown an error. But unfortunately you had only one row in your `X` and one in `y` and they both are of same size and it passed `assert` it had to make.
- And `np.ravel` converts an multi-dimensional array into `1D` array. So if you doing a binary classification, you would be having a `2x2` matrix, whose flattened array would have been four elements and the assignment would have worked. But the ravelling you had made releases $n(c)^2$ elements. So there you go `ValueError`. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

I hope my other [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/decision-tree-used-for-calculating-precision-accuracy-and-recall-class-breakd/27137#27137) on confusion matrices may clear things a little more.

Hope it clears some mistakes you are making.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, i really appreciate it. I am a newbie in the DS world, so still has a lot of confusions on how to use these technics. I will need more helps on this, so appreciate in advance for your future help as well.